# Bones disappear/get deleted when applying pose as rest pose

Tags: rigging, bones, pose-mode

So I was messing around with a really large model in blender and found that the bones are really small and hard to select, but I'm still able to pose the model in spite of this nuance after resizing it to be a bit smaller and displaying the bones as something else other than octahedral, like envelope or b-bones. However, when I try to apply a new pose as the rest position, all of the bones disappear entirely or get deleted, and I can't further pose it. What does this mean, and how do I work around this?

Here's an Imgur link to the process:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/crAYb.jpg

Comment: Can you add screenshots? That sounds really strange.

Comment: Sure thing. I added an Imgur link this time to show what was going on. It's very loaded and specific.

Comment: My first guess is that some scale is getting applied, and all the bones shrink. I might iterate through them with a script and increase their length.

Comment: For future reference, please edit such images into the question. There is a built-in image adder.